# Why won't this code read the data from the pipe?

Tags: c, posix

I am looking at how to write pipes and am trying to understand how the standard c library exposes them in some detail. I wrote the following code and would expect that the output would be

```
2 3
MAJOR ERROR
BYE
```

However the second line does not show up. Could someone explain why that is happening?

```
int main()
{
    int rc;
    int p[2];
    char buffer[40];

    close(2);

    rc = pipe(p);
    printf("%d %d\n", p[0], p[1]);
    FILE* pipeWrite = fdopen(p[1], "w");
    fprintf(pipeWrite, "MAJOR ERROR\n");
    close(p[1]);

    rc = read(p[0], buffer, 40);
    buffer[rc] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    printf("BYE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Pipes are IPC tools. Where's your other process?

Comment: Is one really necessary? I believe I'm technically allowed to use them as simple file descriptors. I know this would never be done in an actual environment, but I'm doing this to simply understand how they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing into the pipe using standard IO buffered operations (`fprintf(3)`), but then close the filedescriptor before flushing output. Add `fflush(pipeWrite);` immediately before the `close(p[1]);` call and see if your output is what you expect. (You could also use `fclose(pipeWrite);`, as closing the standard IO stream will also flush the output.)

See the `setvbuf(3)` manpage for more details on the standard IO stream buffering options.

Answer (score 0):

> int main() {
>       int rc;
>       int p[2];
>       char buffer[40];
>
> ```
> close(2);
>
> rc = pipe(p);
> printf("%d %d\n", p[0], p[1]);
> FILE* pipeWrite = fdopen(p[1], "w");
> fprintf(pipeWrite, "MAJOR ERROR\n");
> close(p[1]);
>
> rc = read(p[0], buffer, 40);
> buffer[rc] = '\0';
> printf("%s\n", buffer);
> printf("BYE\n");
>
> return 0; }
> ```

try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int rc;
    int p[2];
    char buffer[40];

    close(2);

    pipe(p);
    printf("%d %d\n", p[0], p[1]);
    /*    FILE* pipeWrite = fdopen(p[1], "w");
      fprintf(p[1], "MAJOR ERROR\n");*/
    if((rc = write(p[1], "MAJOR ERROR\n", 12)) > 0)
      printf("Wrote to pipe\n");
    close(p[1]);

    if((rc = read(p[0], buffer, 40)) > 0)
      {    buffer[rc] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    printf("BYE\n");
      }

    return 0;
}
```

one of many ways to skin a cat